# Solidity: Difference between require and if, need to use address when calling function on a smart contract

Tags: solidity, addresses, require

I have a question if the two functions below differ as I have written approach 2 but no 1 was the solution. Earlier in the contract `Dangerous d;` is defined which refers to a different smart contract.

Approach 1:

```
function () public payable { 
    if(address(d).balance >= deposited) {
        d.withdraw(deposited);
    } 
}
```

Approach 2:

```
function() public payable  {
    require(d.balance>=deposited);
    d.withdraw(deposited);
}
```

Both approaches differ by if/require and by the fact that once directly calls balance on d while no 1 calls it on address(d). Is there any difference?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: a `require()` will output the error string as return value from the contract and a `debug.traceTransaction()` would catch it, so you could see what's wrong. an `if then else` wouldnt

Comment: Thank you @Nulik! And is there also a difference in terms of calling the object vs. address(object)?

Comment: the balance function can be only applied to accounts, so if `d` is not an address, it simply wont compile

Comment: unless the `d` contract has a `balance` function built in. Then it would use whatever value this function returns (which could very well not be the contract balance) to perform its check